# How to convert json with dynamic root name to C# list

Tags: c#, json, api, json.net

```cs
var stringResult = await HttpHelper.PostAsync(batchUrl, content);
```

I am getting following result as an API response in C# in above stringResult variable after calling above line. I want to convert below "Items" value to C# list. In every result, first GUID is different. How to convert the below result in C# List. I want only Items.

```json
{
    "0934009e-6518-4440-91e3-c252d2e2cc4f": {
        "Status": 200,
        "Headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        },
        "Content": {
            "Items": [{
                    "Timestamp": "2021-10-18T14:00:00Z",
                    "Value": 20.7,
                    "UnitsAbbreviation": "ppm"
                }, {
                    "Timestamp": "2021-10-25T14:00:00Z",
                    "Value": 15.9,
                    "UnitsAbbreviation": "ppm"
                }, {
                    "Timestamp": "2021-11-01T14:00:00Z",
                    "Value": 14.8,
                    "UnitsAbbreviation": "ppm"
                }, {
                    "Timestamp": "2021-11-08T15:00:00Z",
                    "Value": 20.1,
                    "UnitsAbbreviation": "ppm"
                }, {
                    "Timestamp": "2021-11-15T15:00:00Z",
                    "Value": 19.5,
                    "UnitsAbbreviation": "ppm"
                }, {
                    "Timestamp": "2021-11-22T15:00:00Z",
                    "Value": 19.7,
                    "UnitsAbbreviation": "ppm"
                }, {
                    "Timestamp": "2021-11-29T15:00:00Z",
                    "Value": 20.4,
                    "UnitsAbbreviation": "ppm"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What serializer are you using?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama Newtonsoft.Json's DeserializeObject I have used to convert string result to json

Comment: [Does this answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38411344/c-sharp-deserialize-json-unknown-keys)?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama No. I tried with JObject.Parse(stringResult).["Items"].ToObject<Item>(). But getting object reference error. I created a class for mapping "Items"

Answer (score 2):

When some part of the json structure is unknown, you need to explore it manually. There are several ways to do it, but I'm used to passing JObject :

```cs
var root = JObject.Parse(text);
// Unknown name property, then iterate
// When the object has one property, First is a good fit
var response = root.First as JProperty;
var guid = response.Name;
var itemsJson = response.Value["Content"]["Items"];
var items = itemsJson.ToObject<List<Item>>();
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this code

```
List<Item> items = JObject.Parse(stringResult).Properties()
                        .First().Value["Content"]["Items"].ToObject<List<Item>>();

public class Item
{
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public string UnitsAbbreviation { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

go to https://json2csharp.com/
convert your json to C# class.

since your root node is dynamic guid, you cannot directly use class structure deserialization but you can use a inner nodes

**Pseudo Program**

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
WebClient w = new WebClient();
string json = w.DownloadString(new Uri("https://jsonkeeper.com/b/GETO"));
var firstObject = JObject.Parse(json);
var guid = firstObject.Properties().Select(p => p.Name).FirstOrDefault();
//Console.Write(guid);
Root output = firstObject[guid].ToObject<Root>();
Console.Write(output.Content.Items.Count());
```

**The DTO structure**

```
public class Root
{
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public Headers Headers { get; set; }
    public Content Content { get; set; }
}

public class Content
{
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Headers
{
    [JsonProperty("Content-Type")]
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public string UnitsAbbreviation { get; set; }
}
```

here's fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/w5fO0w

Answer (score 0):

I have used below code to get items -

```
           var resultObjects = AllChildren(JObject.Parse(json))
                    .First(c => c.Type == JTokenType.Array )
                    .Children<JObject>();



           foreach (JObject result in resultObjects)
            {
                foreach (JProperty property in result.Properties())
                {
                    
                }
            }
```

And method is -

```
private static IEnumerable<JToken> AllChildren(JToken json)
        {
            foreach (var c in json.Children())
            {
                yield return c;
                foreach (var cc in AllChildren(c))
                {
                    yield return cc;
                }
            }
        }
```